# How to find satellite relative velocity in skyfield?

Tags: python, satellite, skyfield, satellite-navigation

I need to find how fast a satellite is moving relative to me.  I was thinking about using the Python package 'skyfield' but I don't see how I can calculate this:

```
from skyfield.api import EarthSatellite, Topos
import skyfield.api

sat = EarthSatellite('1 43700U 18090A   18335.89431171 +.00000133 +00000-0 +00000-0 0  9993',
                 '2 43700 000.0858 245.4352 0001094 006.6237 164.6135 01.00274015000309')
time_scale = skyfield.api.load.timescale()
time0 = time_scale.utc(2018, 12, 1, 21, 0, 0)
position0 = sat.at(time0)
position0_ITRF = sat.ITRF_position_velocity_error(time0)[:2]

my_loc = Topos('39.0 N', '105.0 W')
```

I am not sure how to convert my_loc to a corresponding location so I can compute a relative satellite velocity.  Should I use a different package that has more functions implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ask “Where is `my_loc` at `time0`:

```
position1 = my_loc.at(time0)
```

then you will have another position object with a `.velocity` that you should be able to compare to your satellite's velocity. You could also do the subtraction beforehand:

```
relative_position = (sat - my_loc).at(time0)
```

Then both the `.position` and `.velocity` of the resulting object should be relative to your location, without your having to subtract them yourself.